# Rails 4 - has_many through controller actions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested, has-many-through

I'm trying to set a has_many trough relationship and I'm new to this

```
#models/partner.rb
class Partner < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :cards_partners
has_many :cards, through: :cards_partners

#models/card.rb
class Card < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :cards_partners
has_many :partners, through: :cards_partners

#models/cards_partner.rb
class CardsPartner < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :card
belongs_to :partner
```

And I specified the controllers

```
#controllers/cards_controller.rb
before_action :set_card, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
def show
  @user = @card.user
  @partners = @card.partners.order(lastname: :desc)
  @partner = @card.partners.new #because I have a modal to create new Partner too
  #address is in a polymorphic table. I have to refactor the if-else      
  if @card.address.street.blank? && @card.address.city.blank?
    @address = @user.address
  else
    @address = @card.address
  end
end

  def create
    @card = current_user.cards.new(card_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @card.save
        format.html { redirect_to @card, notice: 'Card was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @card }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @card.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @card.update(card_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @card, notice: 'Card was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @card }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @card.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

private
    def set_card
      @card = Card.find(params[:id])
    end

def card_params
 params.require(:card).permit(partner_ids: [])
end

#controllers/partners_controller.rb
def partner_params
params.require(:partner).permit(card_ids: [])
end
```

My join table cards_partners is properly set.

To sum up the logic, a User can create Cards and add Partners to this Card.
I set a has_many through between Cards and Partners because I want User to be able to assign already Created Partners to multiple Cards.

I have inside my `cards#show` view a partial that shows all the partners, and a link to add a new one to this card.

I define my `@partners` inside my `card#show` action with (not sure about this since no join specified):

```
@partners = @card.partners.order(lastname: :desc)
```

I can't figure how to specify the card and then creating a new partner from `card#show` view using the link `new_partner_path`.

Any help would be really appreciated.
Thank you a lot

Comment: It would be great if you post your controller action `card#show` and where you are about to create this record (like `card#create`). Or it has just this one line?

Comment: Thank you for your answer zishe. I edited the controller with show, create and update actions. Hope that helps.

Comment: And this `current_user.cards.new(card_params)` works? According to [this](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html) there is no `new` method for your case. So it should be `cards.build`

Comment: I'm not sure what is wrong is your app, i need a view of creation, to understand more. Also you can log your params to properly define it `logger.debug params`

Comment: I changed new to build, even if it woked well you're right. The card creation isn't involved I guess, since It is already created before any new partner creation. I think that my problem is on the understanding of has_many through. I don't know how I can load the partner#new view from card#show passing the :card_id to build the new partner with a relationship (in join table) to this specified card. I understand this like the basic has_many through but I maybe missing something. if I do a link to new_partner_path(@card) I break the routes url.